# Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: entity-framework

I have been looking online for the answer but without success, I have several public classes, do I have to put all my public classes in the `DbContext` part?

For example:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
    // 6 more public classes
}
```

Comment: That depends on what you are doing with those classes. You need one `DbSet` for every table in your database, but you can have as many classes as you like.

Comment: Yes you have to add all your model classes as `DbSet<>` properties in the `ProductContext` class if you want to make changes to these specific database tables.

Comment: Clear answers, thanks